# AAB file shows the key is to weak, how can I update this android key

Tags: android, android-keystore, android-security

AAB file shows the key is to weak, how can I update this android key

I need to know can I able to update the key to a strong one.

> Your Android App Bundle uses an upload certificate with a key that is
> too weak.

Comment: https://www.devopsschool.com/blog/how-to-upload-new-keystore-or-app-signing-key-in-google-play-console-after-lost-or-forget-keystore/ Does this help?

Comment: But the abve blog is for forgot or loss the key

Comment: Yeah.. but you can create a new key with the same process

Comment: New key with same process means same password and alias name